# How correctly can I use sql JOIN and ON statement inside the doctrine addSelect() function

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

```
 public function calculateCandidatesExamScores($examIRI, $groupIRI, int $page =1)
    {
        $firstResult = ($page -1 ) * self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE;

        $dql = $this->createQueryBuilder('examlog');
        $dql->join('examlog.examQuestion', 'question');
        $dql->join('question.tblQuestionOptions', 'option');
        $dql->join('examlog.examUser', 'examRegister');
        $dql->join('examRegister.userGroup', 'group');
        $dql->join('examRegister.user', 'candidate');
        $dql->select('count(examlog.id) totalQuestions, candidate.firstname firstname, candidate.regNumber applicant_ref');
//        $dql->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(q.marks) FROM App\Core\Domain\Entity\TblExamUserLogs logs JOIN App\Core\Domain\Entity\TblQuestions q ON logs.examQuestion = q.id JOIN App\Core\Domain\Entity\TblQuestionOptions op ON q.tblQuestionOptions = op.id WHERE logs.answerText = op.answer) AS score');
        $dql->andWhere('examRegister.exam = :exam AND examRegister.userGroup = :group');
        $dql->setParameter('exam', $examIRI);
        $dql->setParameter('group', $groupIRI);
        $dql->addGroupBy('candidate.firstname, candidate.regNumber');
//        $dql->addOrderBy('score', 'DESC');
        $query = $dql->getQuery()
            ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
            ->setMaxResults(self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE);

        $doctrinePaginator = new DoctrinePaginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);


        return ['totalResults'=> $doctrinePaginator->count(), 'results'=>$doctrinePaginator->getQuery()->getResult()];

    }
```

The above Query works but if I remove the comment on `$dql->addSelect(...` function, it throws the following error `Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'ON' (500 Internal Server Error)`. Please I need to know what am doing wrong and the possible way to get this working. Thank you.

Comment: A SQL query needs to have a select clause.  Why would you want to remove the call to `addSelect()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Select is already on the query. Just using addSelect() to get extra data in a single query

Comment: There is no ON in doctrine because doctrine knows how to connect the tables. Try using WITH https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder

Comment: @FrankB Thanks. Figured that out a while ago that I needed only to remove the ON and use only the property names;